# Transitioning ios 6 to ios 7

Tags: ios, ios7, storyboard

I have an app built on the iOS6 with interface created by storyboard. Should I make another storyboard, specially for iOS7 with Auto Layout, or I can put Auto Layout constraints in already existing storyboard?

An error accured when I checked "Use Auto Layout" in the storyboard's File Inspector, saying that I am trying to use Auto Layout in Prior verison than iOS7.

Comment: Wasn't auto-layout available in iOS 6?

Comment: @GuyKogus yup. Been available since iOS 6.

Comment: Then you should be able to use a single storyboard. Are you using the latest Xcode?

Comment: My Xcode version is 5.1.1.

Comment: What is your deployment target set to?

Comment: You can transit without autolayout if it causes you problems. (Just if you think that autolayout is iOs7 condition - it is not). If you need it for something than ok, but if your project worked on iOs6 and you don't have a specific need for it, than leave it turned off. Implementing it on an old existing project can be a little tricky.

Comment: My deployment target was 5.0. That was the reason why error accured. Thank you all for your help and advises!